# backbone.js marionette and co

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

i am a beginner in the backbonejs world und bought a book from Addy Osmani’s Backbonejs Application. i am reading the book and i try to build an application with backbonejs. Somewhere in the book, he wrote a section about backbonejs extendsion and expose how to use marionettejs. I visited on Github backbonejs extendsion site, they have many extendsion included marionettejs. Now i am confused about using backbonejs, should i use extendsion like Marionettejs too or not? I know that extendsion can brings many advantages for webdevelopment, when i gonna use backbonejs then i should use marionettejs too? When it is useful to use extendsion when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find Marionette to be a useful addition to Backbone, because it reduces the amount of repetitive code you need to write (unbinding event listeners when views close, rendering one view for each item in a collection and attaching it to the DOM, etc.).

There's a nice (short) comparison of Marionette and plain Backbone here: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#boilerplate-rendering-code

Ultimately, the best tool for you will depend on what you want to achieve and what your preferences are.

Full disclosure: I may not be entirely objective, since I'm writing a [book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction). But I'm sure other members will provide you with their own opinions.

Comment: i bought your book, hope it will be useful for me.

Comment: I hope so too! In any case, it will help you understand how the bits and pieces go together (views, models/collection, etc.). That information will be useful even if you decide to only use plain Backbone.

Comment: i have a question about amd and marionettejs. Can i use RequireJS to load marionettejs?

Comment: Yes, there's a blog post on that here: http://johndavidmathis.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/seamlessly-integrate-marionette-with-requirejs/

Comment: There's also an example (using CoffeeScript) here: https://github.com/t2k/backbone.marionette-RequireJS

Comment: what is better choice? requirejs or marionettejs module library?

Comment: I personally like the Marionette modules to structure and organize code. You can then use your back end framework to package and deliver the various javascript files with a single request (e.g. Rails' asset pipeline).

Comment: using requirejs is for me more confident. Don't know why. I have read your book already 47 sites, it is really easy to understand. I am really satisfied.

Comment: i have a question about modules. for example MyApp.module("Foo", function(){}); MyApp.module("Foo.Bar", function(){}); is Bar submodule from Foo right? If yes, it is possible to write Foo.module("Bar", function(){}); instead MyApp.module("Foo.Bar", function(){});?

Comment: i am really confused about event. it has a few opportunity how to trigger an event and register.

Comment: i really don't know, in which situation i should use event or method call? Please need some advice.